# Is it possible to simple-react-code-editor as a Formik field component?

Tags: reactjs, formik, code-editor, react-simple-code-editor

Trying to get this form field component to take a simple-react-code-editor:

not sure if I'm going about this the right way by trying to pass props form the `useField` hook, but it works for textfield tags, so thought the same method could apply to this as well. Although, I get the feeling the `onValueChange` callback is different from the `onChange` callback that this component doesn't have. Is there a way to add it somehow?

Editor Component:

```
const MyEditor = ({value, onChange}) => {

  const highlight = (value) => {
    return(
      <Highlight {...defaultProps} theme={theme} code={value} language="sql">
        {({ tokens, getLineProps, getTokenProps }) => (
          <>
            {tokens.map((line, i) => (
              <div {...getLineProps({ line, key: i })}>
                {line.map((token, key) => (
                  <span {...getTokenProps({ token, key })} />
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </Highlight>
    )
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      value={value}
      onValueChange={onChange}
      highlight={highlight}
      padding={'40px'}
      style={styles.root}
    />
  );
}

export default MyEditor;
```

Form with Field Component as MyEditor (tried using useField hook):

```
const FormQueryTextBox = ({...props}) => {

    const [field] = useField(props);

    return (
        <MyEditor onChange={field.onChange} value={field.value}/>
    )
}

const validationSchema = yup.object({
    query_name: yup
        .string()
        .required()
        .max(50)
});

const AddQueryForm = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Formik
                validateOnChange={true}
                initialValues={{
                    query:""
                }}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    console.log(data);
                }}
            >
                {() => (
                    <Form>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                placeholder="query name"
                                name="query_name"
                                type="input"
                                as={TextField}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                name="query"
                                type="input"
                                as={FormQueryTextBox}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}
```

components render without errors, but as I type the text doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I just need to customize my onChange with the setter from the useFormikContext hook like this:

```
const FormQueryTextBox = ({...props}) => {

    const [field] = useField(props);
    const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

    return (
        <MyEditor {...field} {...props} onChange={val => {
            setFieldValue(field.name, val)
        }}/>
    )
}
```